# How do I hire companions in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing a sneak style character with companion and liked that, but in one battle with a dragon my companion died. Can I hire a new companion in Skyrim? If yes, then where to hire them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find them in several Inns and some are quest-related. [Here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Followers) is a incomplete list of several followers.

Additionally you can buy a wardog for 500 gold in front of the stables in Markarth who is independent of a human follower (you can use both).

Comment: +! didn't know the wardog was separate from your follower, nice!

Answer (score 2):

Companions are people you work with usually, or sometimes affected to your service.

> For example, Lydia is affected to you if you became Thane of Whiterun. There is a mage that will accept to follow you in the Winterhold college if you help her.

I guess there is more, but I don't know all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to another companion and say follow me. But there's a bug that they say you already have a follower 'cause you didn't dismiss it but he\she died. Bug fix is for Farkas quest after companions quest line.

Comment: Don't forget about non-npc companions, they don't disaccept